# Implementing Forgot password functionality

Tags: hash, passwords

I understand that a hash salt combination is the ideal way to store a users password. I also know that hashes are one way and not really possible to get the original plain text.

So, if one is to implement a "forgot password" function in a web application, what would be the best way to get to the original plain text password so we can send that back to the user?

Hopefully this isn't too ignorant of a question.

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. You can either change their password to a new (random) one and send that, or you send them a link that will let them access a page where they can enter a new password.

Comment: Alright. I can accept that. Not sure why my question got a -2 vote.